# Symfony multiple routes pointing to the same action

Tags: symfony, routes

My Symfony app has an existing route, `log/add` which calls the function `addAction` successfully.

Recently I've had to add a variant of that route which has a timestamp at the end like so, `log/add/1429228800`. What I need is for the second route to point at the same action as the first.

My issue is the second route generates the following error:

> No route found for "GET /log/add/1429228800"

My routes are set in yml like the following:

```
log_add:
    pattern:   /log/add
    defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Default:add }

log_add_timestamped:
    pattern:   /log/add/{timestamp}
    defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Default:add }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one route

```
log_add:
    pattern:   /log/add/{timestamp}
    defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Default:add, timestamp: null}
```

Set a default value to the timestamp parameter (`null` in my example, but you can set something else)

Comment: You can enhance by adding requirements : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements